# Set up an email domain with Postfix and Dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I am very new to the Linux world so please forgive me.

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.10 x86 and I have installed Rails3, Nginx, Mysql and Passenger. All are up and running.

I want to set up mail so I would like to use `myname@blurmedia.co.uk`.

I have installed Postfix and can send and receive mail using `sendmail`.

However after doing some research I need Dovecot for POP3 and IMAP, how would I do this and how could I then use `myname@blurmedia.co.uk` in a client like Thunderbird or Outlook?

If you need any information please tell me as I'm not sure what you would need to see?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to send mail from that VPS with `myname@blurmedia.co.uk` as the `From:` address? Do you want mail sent to `myname@blurmedia.co.uk` to be delivered to your VPS? If the latter, do you control the `blurmedia.co.uk` domain?

Comment: I can already send and receive mail from and to the VPS, I would like to be able to pick my mail up from a client like `Thunderbird` or `Outlook` so I installed dovecot keeping the default settings but It hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you need an extra bit of software to act as an IMAP server for email clients to use.  Dovecot is a good choice.

If your email is already being delivered locally by postfix (i.e. you have a local file to which new mail is written as it arrives), you're half-way there.  After a bit of `aptitude install dovecot-imapd`, things may well just work: the default configs are pretty good.  Make sure that your firewall allows TCP connections on port 143, and try pointing your email client at it.

When you get things working, do consider using some form of encryption.  IMAPS is a good choice, and (at least in the Debian package) dovecot will use both, albeit with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: In a controlled environment, a self-signed certificate can work nearly as well as a CA-signed certificate, and is vastly cheaper. Simply configure the MUA to only accept a given certificate from the remote host; I'm not sure exactly how to do that in Thunderbird, but in fetchmail one simply adds `sslfingerprint "md:5f:in:ge:rp:ri:nt"` to the `poll` configuration stanza, where the MD5 fingerprint can be obtained by `openssl x509 -md5 -fingerprint < cert_file`. Remember to update this when you update the certificate or connections will (should!) fail.